# Adding a comment with spaces: Only one comment allowed per 15 seconds (inappropriate error message)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

When adding a short comment with trailing spaces (to trick the 15 character limit), the error message is incorrect as it says: "Only one comment allowed per 15 seconds"

This is what I mean (replicated on this site):

EDIT: [video proof (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9D2WB1ELMU)

[image: screenshot]

EDIT: Are you supposed to downvote just because you cannot replicate? I'm only trying to contribute. :(

P.S. I am using **Google Chrome 10.0.648.205**

Comment: because commenting is not chat. We've got, well, chat, for that.

Comment: Eh? Can't repro. I get the "Comments must be at least 15..." message.

Comment: yes, it's the 15 char limit. and yes, I am reporting inappropriate error message.

Comment: Maybe there's also a comment per periode of time limit?

Comment: Just tested, yes, there is also a time limit. It just shows this one before the 15 char. one.

Comment: i waited for about a minute before submitting a new comment.

Comment: No repro from me either, with two comments posted - one over the 15-char limit and one under. I waited about 10 seconds after posting the first comment.

Comment: What comment do you test it with? It HAS to be a short string under 15 chars with trailing spaces to make up for 15 char limit. e.g. wtf?_____________ where underscore is a space char.

Comment: @BadDisplayName That's what I did, yeah.

Comment: Could not reproduce.

Comment: It's `Status-Norepro` @Oded :)

Comment: @hims056 - meh. The issue of timer resets is by design. Debated with myself if I should just delete this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still cannot reproduce this, even with your video.

You may have a proxy that is caching the old error.

What do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: A cheese cart, a Jewish wedding and Gwen Stefani.

Comment: yes, I am behind the proxy. full.js status is 304 (Not Modified)

Comment: @Bad: No.  What do you see for the AJAX request when submitting the second comment?

Comment: 409 Conflitct. how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

When you submit a 15-char comment with trailing spaces, the server rejects it as an invalid comment, **but the time limit still kicks in**.

Therefore, if you submit another comment right afterwards, you get the 5-second error, because you submitted a (failed) comment less than 5 seconds ago.  (This check happens before the comment length check)

Comment: as you can see in my screenshot I've waited over 30 sec before trying to submit a comment with spaces. The error message shown was incorrect. However, submitting a valid length comment after 5 or more seconds works fine, therefore there's a problem in error handling.

Comment: @Bad: I just tried it; my description is correct.  Can you post a video of the problem?

Comment: posted a link to video in the question